# How do I load a fragment from an activity and pull a variable into it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a simple app that, as of right now, contains main_activity.kt and fragment_results.kt and their xml files.  The premise of the app is that the user scans a barcode and then hits a button.  A fragment comes up and displays all of the data tied to that barcode. Once I understand how to do this part, I will extend it so the user can add barcodes to the spreadsheet but that's down the road.

The problem I'm running into with Kotlin is that it looks like a lot of stuff is deprecated and while android studio is great at showing me the new ways to do things, a simple to follow tutorial is hard to find.

main_activity.kt

```
package com.example.barcode

import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import com.budiyev.android.codescanner.AutoFocusMode
import com.budiyev.android.codescanner.CodeScanner
import com.budiyev.android.codescanner.DecodeCallback
import com.budiyev.android.codescanner.ErrorCallback
import com.budiyev.android.codescanner.ScanMode
import com.example.barcode.databinding.ActivityMainBinding


private const val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 101

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var codeScanner: CodeScanner



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupPermissions()
        codeScanner()
    }

    private fun codeScanner() {

        codeScanner = CodeScanner(this, binding.scannerView)

        codeScanner.apply {codeScanner
            camera = CodeScanner.CAMERA_BACK
            formats = CodeScanner.ALL_FORMATS

            autoFocusMode = AutoFocusMode.SAFE
            scanMode = ScanMode.SINGLE
            isAutoFocusEnabled = true
            isFlashEnabled = false

            decodeCallback = DecodeCallback {
                    binding.button.text = getString(R.string.searchButtonLabel, it.text)

            }
            errorCallback = ErrorCallback {
                    Log.e("Main", "Camera Initilization failed ${it.message}")
            }
        }
        binding.scannerView.setOnClickListener {
            codeScanner.startPreview()
            binding.button.text = getString(R.string.resetButtonLabel)
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        codeScanner.startPreview()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        codeScanner.releaseResources()
        super.onPause()
    }

    private fun setupPermissions() {
        val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            makeRequest()
        }
    }
    private fun makeRequest(){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
            CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        when (requestCode) {
            CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isEmpty() || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    Toast.makeText(this,"You need the camera for this app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }else{

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

My resultsFragment.kt is a stock blank .kt.  Haven't worked on that programming yet.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create

Comment: Richard,  I appreciate you trying to help but I can't get this to work.